# .addClass to element adds a styling then removes, how do I fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code

```
var prev;
function addClass( classname, element ) {
    prev = cn;
    var cn = document.getElementById(element);

    $(cn).addClass("selected");
}
```

The element in the dom look like this:

```
<div class="arrowgreen">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="addClass('selected','first')" id="first">Manager</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="addClass('selected','second')" id="second" ">Planner</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="addClass('selected','third')" id="third">Administrator</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For 'arrowgreen' I have a styling which changes the li styling on rollover and click.
When an element is clicked on, I want to apply the 'selected' classname to the element.
It does this for a split second and then reverts back.

The css looks like

```
.arrowgreen li a.selected{
    color: #26370A;
    background-position: 100% -64px;
}
```

Comment: This does nothing useful `prev = cn`...

Comment: I guess your using Jquery.Dont use **addClass** method its a jquery`s predefined method name.

Comment: @dreamweiver that means nothing, there are different namespaces/scopes

Comment: Since most of your code is `javascript`, I'm presuming you don't have jQuery included in your file.

Comment: elclanrs, I was going to remove styling from the menu option previously selected then apply it to selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zGKjy/)**

In usage of `$` in your code, I see that you are using jQuery.
There is no need to set `onclick` internally. 
Let's jQuery handle it for you:

```
// wait for dom ready
$(function () {
    // when user clicks on elements
    $('.arrowgreen li a').on('click', function (e) {
        // prevent default the behaviour of link
        e.preventDefault();

        // remove old `selected` classes from elements
        $('.arrowgreen li a').removeClass('selected');

        // add class `selected` to current element
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHhGu/)

There was an error in your HTML, a `"` that opened a new string after `onclick`.

```
var prev;

function addClass(classname, element) {
    var cn = document.getElementById(element);
    prev = cn; //does nothing useful really
    $(cn).addClass("selected");
}

<div class="arrowgreen">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="addClass('selected','first')" id="first">Manager</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="addClass('selected','second')" id="second">Planner</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="addClass('selected','third')" id="third">Administrator</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Remember to include `jQuery` in your page!

There is a way to do this without jQuery anyway:

```
function addClass(classname, element) {
    var cn = document.getElementById(element);
    prev = cn; //does nothing useful really
    cn.className += " " + classname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar way to do it:

```
(function ($) {

    $('.arrowgreen > ul > li > a').on('click', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

    }); 

}(jQuery));
```